# How to add each of checked checkboxes to a signle row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have several checkboxes that contain names (ids as referrence to database) - see code below. How can I select all checked values and add them to database (via MySQL) each row for each checked?

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="names[]">John
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="names[]">Peter
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="names[]">Mike
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="names[]">Kattie
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
```

After clicking "send" with requiered checked names, the result in database should look like this (I selected John and Mike):

Id

1

3

(only selected ones)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your `input`s in a `<form>` element and give this form a method of `post`:

```
<form method="post"> 
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="names[]" />John
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="names[]" />Peter
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="names[]" />Mike
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="names[]" />Kattie
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send" />
</form>
```

This will allow you to *post* submitted data from your form inputs to your PHP.

**Note**: If your HTML is in a different file (ie not in the same file as your form) you can add the `action` attribute to your form (eg: `action="fileWithPHP.php"`)

Now you can access all checked checkboxes in your PHP using `$_POST['names']`. This will allow you to get your array of checked values. You can then use a `foreach` loop to loop through every value in your array:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['names'])) {
  $names = $_POST['names'];

  foreach($names as $name) {
    echo "Add " . $name . " to db here<br />"; // add $name to db
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the inputs around a `<form>` and send it to php and retrieve using `$_GET` or `$_POST` and update the database.

I have used `POST` method here.

HTML:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="names[]">John
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="names[]">Peter
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="names[]">Mike
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="names[]">Kattie
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(!empty($_POST['names'])) {
    foreach($_POST['names'] as $check) {
            echo $check; //instead of echo you can insert it to the database
    }
}
```